Usage of cubic equation Vieta's formula
I explained to my kid Vieta's formula of quadratic equation and showed that it can be used to solve quadratic equation (from $x_1+x_2$ and $x_1x_2$ to get $x_1-x_2$) and cubic equation (Cardano's approach).
Then I explained there's also a Vieta's formula for the cubic equation. However, this seems is only good for an algebra exercise to derive it. I wonder, can the cubic equation's Vieta's formula be used to derive some results?
I searched on this and math.stackexchange.com forum, but only found some questions that can utilize the formula. Is there some nice results that can be achieved from cubic equation's vieta formula, just as the examples above of quadratic equation's Vieta formula ?

Since in school to solve third degree equations  you have to fin one root  to divide  to come to a quadratic equation. So it is nice to know that the absolute value is the product of the roots. If you have 3 roots in whole numbers the rest also helps.

One thing that has always intrigued me about the Vieta formulas is that they give a perfect correspondence between ordered sets of complex numbers $(a_1, a_2,\cdots,a_n)$ and unordered sets of complex numbers $\{r_1,r_2,\cdots, r_n\}$. It's strange and kind of magical. Take an unordered set of $n$ numbers, set up the polynomial $$f(z)=(z-r_1)(z-r_2)\cdots(z-r_n)$$ and multiply it out to get $$f(z)=z^n+a_1z^{n-1}\cdots+a_{n-1}z+ a_n$$ The coefficients $a_k$ are given by the Vieta formulas.
I think of two worlds: one is the world of ordered tuples that we are used to, and then the other is the world of unordered sets. Let's call them Ord and Sym, for symmetric.
Ord and Sym are like parallel universes. The wormhole from Sym to Ord is easy: multiply out the factored polynomial. This is Vieta. Going back is weird and hard, because we have to solve for the roots of the polynomial in terms of the coefficients, like the quadratic formula.
We are used to navigating Ord in the case of $n=3$ and when the values are restricted to be real. This would be the space ${\bf R}^3$ that we navigate. On the basis of this, our brains can kind of conceptualize moving in ${\bf C}^n$. But we have a strange twin that navigates Sym as we navigate Ord and it is fun to try to visualize this twin.
Here is something concrete. Focus on Ord with $n=2$ and restricted to real values. Say we are positioned at $(b,c)$ in the usual Cartesian plane. We take our position and defined the quadratic polynomial $f(x)=x^2+bx+c$. Since the roots of a quadratic with real coefficients come in conjugate pairs, we know what our Sym twin is doing as we navigate in our Cartesian plane. We can think of our twin as being a pair of complex numbers (points) that are mirror images of one another across the $x$-axis. As we move around the real Cartesian plane, this symmetrically related pair of points dances around, sometimes coming together to kiss on the real axis, and then part ways, keeping the symmetry of a conjugate pair of complex numbers.

Thanks for the beautiful image, about the parallel universes and wormhole in between. Sorry i'm a bit slow here, may I ask, this interpretation, besides a nice "point of view", would it leads to some powerful results? It rings a bell to me about V.I. Arnold's Abel's theorem in problems and solutions , where he explained the perturbation of coefficients caused the perturbation of roots, then proved Abel's theorem from a geometric point of view.

@athos where this goes is the symmetric product of an algebraic curve. It is a nice surprise that the symmetric product of a 1-dimensional complex curve, i.e., a Riemann surface, is smooth. In higher dimensions, the symmetric product has singularities.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_product_of_an_algebraic_curve
This is related to Jacobian varieties.

I wrote up some problems that may be of interest in this general direction. My writeup can be found in full here; it was initially intended for use in an Algebra 2 course, but – as may be apparent within the first two pages – it ended up being a bit more difficult than intended. The final page contains the problems; enjoy!
